# Showing/Hiding a div based on data, without loading non-displayed data in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In my app I have a search page which loads in data based on a user's query. Each result (comes in waves of 10) has two fields I want to dynamically switch between: "imgs" and "smallImgs".

In short, if a result's `smallImgs.length == true` then I want to load up those images. If it has no length then I want to load up its `imgs`.

I'm aware of `ng-hide` and `ng-show`, and I could do a simple true/false statement in the template to show or hide the `imgs`/`smallImgs`. But from what I can tell, even if I have `ng-hide` enabled on an element it still loads in that data (and would hence download the images to the client).

The only way I've thought of achieving this is in my controller, on the `$resource` call that grabs my data:

```
 $scope.itemSearch.get({query:$routeParams.query, page:$routeParams.page}, function(data){
    $scope.posts = data.posts;
    for(var i = 0; i<$scope.posts.length; i++){
      $scope.posts[i].imgs = testImgs($scope.posts[i]);
    }
  });

var testImgs = function(data){
  if (data.smallImgs.length){
    return data.smallImgs;
  } else{
    return data.imgs;
  }
}
```

Unfortunately I haven't gotten this working yet. Is this the best way to achieve this? Is there an Angular way to take care of this in the view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I'd do is add a method to your controller for this:

```
$scope.getImages = function () {
    // add the logic to get the correct array here
};
```

Then just use that in the view, e.g.

```
<div ng-repeat="image in getImages()" />
```

Here's an [example jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geJ4q/).

Comment: your example is not asynchronous

Comment: Why would it be asynchronous?

Comment: @quinnirill This is close, but I don't want an "ng-repeat" here as I only want to use one image and this method took my url and made one broken image for each character in the URL. The solution was to have `$scope.getImages` return an array with one entry.

Answer (score 0):

$scope.itemSearch.get({query:$routeParams.query, page:$routeParams.page}) - if this returns promise you can do so

```
$scope.getImages = $scope.itemSearch.get({query:$routeParams.query, page:$routeParams.page});

<div ng-repeat="image in getImages" />
```

Comment: You can't call a promise.